# Sql Server sequence number

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to generate a partitioned sequence number in SQL server.  The goal is to have each department have its own sequence, but within a department the numbers must be unique.  The numbers are assigned when another record is inserted and if multiple users generate multiple records all of the sequence numbers must be unique.  I've created a table to hold the next value:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DepartmentSequence](
    [DepartmentId] [int] NOT NULL, -- FK to dbo.Department
    [NextSequenceValue] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Sequence_DepartmentId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([DepartmentId] ASC)
```

And a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[apGetNextSequenceNumber] @DepartmentId int AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @result INT

    UPDATE  dbo.DepartmentSequence
    SET     @result = NextSequenceValue,
            NextSequenceValue = NextSequenceValue + 1
    WHERE   DepartmentId = @DepartmentId

    RETURN @result

END
```

Will this function as I expect?  What about if its used in a transaction which is later rolled back?

EDIT:  I've looked into the Sequence object in SQL server, but it doesn't help as each department needs its own unique sequence set.  Department is another table in the system, meaning that any number can be created by users (system admins).  I've updated the table / proc to be more clear about this.

Comment: Yes it will work as you expect - if a transaction is rolled back then you will have a gap in the sequence.

Comment: SEQUENCE in SQL 2012+ may do bit of this for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx, though you would still need to keep track of the individual sequences manually so it may not add much.

Comment: A sequence table like this is very likely to result in performance issues (I have a system that uses one, it's very easy to get long-running processes to cause blocking on this now-critical table). Use the `SEQUENCE` object as has been recommended.

Comment: @DStanley So the change from UPDATE statement in the proc won't be rolled back even if its used within a transaction set of statements?

Answer (score 0):

You are working in SQL Server 2012. It has a `SEQUENCE` object type that does exactly what you wanted:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Department1Sequece
AS int
START WITH 0;
```

Use:

```
SET @NextValue = NEXT VALUE FOR Department1Sequence
```

Values from a sequence are guaranteed to be unique, unless you specify `CYCLE`, in which case the guarantee reduces to one-dimensional movement of the values. Check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ff878091.aspx).

Comment: This is not exactly what I want; departments can be created arbitrarily by end users of the system.  I'd have to create a new Sequence ever time a Department row is added (and remove it if removed).  I've edited the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Have you considered dynamically creating and querying sequences for different departments? Or just use one sequence for all departments?

Comment: Dynamically creating the sequences would require privileges not appropriate to give from a web server.  One sequence for all is out of the question as the departments belong to clients which are competitors.